# Mac OSX Option/command on middle button

Tags: mac, mouse

I have a regular USB mouse, and I was wondering if I can bind Command or Option to my middle mouse button? How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a mouse with a middle button to test, but [Better Touch Tool](http://www.boastr.de/) may work for you.

Comment: Link only answers are not really very helpful. Can you provide context and use the link for reference?

Comment: It didn't work, I can only turn my middle button to key combinations like Option+E ect...